# Can't play Facebook videos with Opera browser

Tags: video, browser, opera, facebook

I can't seem to play any video on facebook using Opera browser, the error I am getting is

```
Video Unavailable 
We are having trouble playing this video.
```

Here is a screenshot of the error I am getting:

[image: screenshot]

I have tried to install flash player & shockwave player it has been listed under plugins of Opera but still I am getting the same error. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay it is fixed now. If anybody curios about it you have to install flash player from this link exactly

https://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/